# Django Queryset filter

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset, django-orm, drf-queryset

My django table contains a field that contains comma-separated strings.

```
class RawData(TimeStampModelMixin):
       id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True)
       media = models.TextField()
```

media column will hold values like 'Multimedia, TV', 'Multimedia, TV Station'. I need to filter Rawdata table rows such that media column contains 'TV' or 'Multimedia'. __icontains doesn't provide the accurate result. If I do

```
Rawdata.objects.filter(media__contains='TV')
```

then it will return both  'Multimedia, TV', 'Multimedia, TV Station' rows. But I need only the 'Multimedia, TV' row.

Is there any way to achieve this via queryset API?

Comment: Any reason not to normalize the datamodel, e.g. create a MediaType table relationship or something alike?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, normalization has been ruled out. We are looking for a solution within the current denormal state.

Comment: `Rawdata.objects.filter(media__icontains='TV')` this should work

Answer (score 1):

As Hedde suggested, better create model like `MediaType` and set proper relationship:

```
class MediaType(models.Model):
       name = models.TextField()

class RawData(TimeStampModelMixin):
       id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True)
       media = models.ManyToManyField(MediaType)
```

Then you will be sure, that seeking for a specific type(s) you will not be mistaken with some similar types.

EDIT: because of above solution is not possible for this particular situation, there is an alternative with `Q` object (symbol `|` means `or`):

```
from django.db.models import Q
Rawdata.objects.filter(Q(media__contains='TV,') | Q(media__endswith='TV'))
```

As I understand it correctly, every situation that `'TV'` is inside `media` field, it has to be in the end of the string or followed directly by a comma.

Comment: Thanks. But at this stage normalizing is out of the question. Know of any other way?

Comment: @SaifulIslam Edited with hopefully satisfacting solution.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best answer. but seeing the exact need you have maybe can do the job with the data you have.

```
Rawdata.objects.filter(
    media__startswith='Multimedia',
    media__endswith='TV'
)
```